# Remove bottom border from parent div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to remove bottom border from parent div. I have written following HTML code but I think my approach is not right. See this image
[image]

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="my-label">
    <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ECECEC;">
        <div style="border: 1px solid #ECECEC; border-bottom: #fff; width: 100px; height: 30px; margin-left: 30px">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Sp9Va/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a pseudo class to add a 1px line across the bottom of it.

Here is the new css:

```
.tab {
    border: 1px solid #ECECEC; 
    border-bottom: 0 solid white; 
    width: 100px; height: 30px; 
    margin-left: 30px; 
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.tab:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

Finally, a fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sp9Va/2/)

Comment: No problem, best of luck in your design mate!

Answer (score 2):

Position it relatively and nudge it down just 1px, so that it covers its parent's border:

```
position:relative;
top:1px;
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/Sp9Va/5/)

Comment: +1 this is what I first did but some how our approaches differed.

Answer (score 1):

The border of the tab is inset into the container; it doesn't cover the container's border.

You can set a negative bottom margin to correct that:

```
.headerbar {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ECECEC;
}

.headertab {
    border: 1px solid #ECECEC; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 30px; 
    margin-left: 30px; 
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    padding: 10px
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Sp9Va/4/

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
margin-bottom: -1px;
```

in order to overlap borders.

You must also use `border-bottom-color: #fff` instead of `border-bottom: #fff` in order to keep the width and the style.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sp9Va/6/)